# Connection timed out: connect

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

When i am trying to deploy my application from Eclipse  am getting the following error 
                Deploying frontend ------------
               java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Any idea on how to remove this ?

Comment: Do you have a stable internet connection?

Comment: Yes i do have a stable internet connection.

Comment: I restarted Eclipse and it started working :)